# How to write "frameborder" and "scrolling" for iframe in HTML5?

Tags: html, iframe

Are these attributes of iframe deprecated in html5: `frameborder`, `scrolling`? Should I use css instead?  Because I want to use css.

```
<iframe src="iframe_ekle.html" width="300px" style="border-style:none; overflow:hidden">
</iframe>
```

But when I do this, border disappears but overflow has no any effect in my page.  That is scrollbar still appears.

Comment: Yes, both attributes are HTML 4 only ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe))

Answer (score 1):

width does not include px when using the html attribute, only in css style.  Just width="300".

```
<iframe src="iframe_ekle.html" width="300" style="border-style:none; overflow:hidden">
```

Also it may help to add a "height" attribute too.

```
<iframe src="iframe_ekle.html" width="300" style="height:600px;border-style:none; overflow:hidden">
```

Comment: thank you iamdev I should have added height attribute.

Comment: This does not address the questions asked.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no “deprecated” concept in HTML5. They are declared as “obsolete”, but according to HTML5 CR, browsers are expected to keep supporting to them. Whether you should use CSS instead is a matter of opinion; HTML5 CR expresses the opinion that you should.

Regarding the issue of scrollbar still appearing, that’s a separate problem, and it should be asked as a separate question, with adequate information included in the question itself. Make sure that anyone can reconstruct the problem from the information included in the question alone.